# Create array from cleaned tags

Tags: php, regex

On my website, I let the user send tags like this:

```
tag tagtwo anothertag
```

I only want to allow them to use single spaces and letters, so I want to remove numbers, dashes, double spaces, etc. So an invalid string would be:

```
tag       tag2 another-tag
```

I have the following code to do this, but I don't know the correct regex to use.

```
$tags = strtolower($_POST['imgTags']);
$tags = preg_replace("/regex/", "", $tags);
$tagArray = explode(" ", $tags);
```

What is the correct regEx to do this?
Also, I might want to replace é and ö with e and o.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove anything but letters and spaces:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/[^a-z ]/i", "", $tags);
```

Then this will collapse consecutive spaces:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/ {2,}/", " ", $tags);
```

If you want to allow other kinds of whitespace characters, but also replace them with single spaces, try this instead:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/[^a-z\s]/i", "", $tags);
$tags = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $tags);
```

Regarding your last sentence: there is no generic way to this. You will have to add specific rules. However, `preg_replace_callback` might help you in determining the unmodified letters.

Comment: Nice, but you should probably use \s to filter out newlines and tabs and whatnot.

Comment: I thought he really only wants normal spaces, and the first line gets rid of all other whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer, that helped me out ;)

Answer (score 1):

To keep just letters and white spaces use:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $tags);
```

To normalize spaces add:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $tags);
```

Comment: I don't want numbers either and no consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 1):

> so I want to remove numbers, dashes, double spaces

`/([0-9\-]|[\s]{2,})/` should work as the regex

Comment: That works kind of, but it doesn't remove  ' or é and it remove all spaces, even the first one.

Comment: but that removes consecutive spaces completely instead of collapsing them down to one space?

Comment: That will remove double spaces instead of converting them to singles, no?

Comment: @Asad True, it will remove double spaces and not collapse them.

Comment: There are several answers here (I posted one too, but then deleted) that do it in two steps. Those should work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all replace multiple spaces and tabs with one:

```
/([ \t])[ \t]*/$1/
```

Then replace everything but letters and spaces with null:

```
/[^A-Za-z ]+//
```

---

**PHP Code**

```
$tags = preg_replace('/([ \t])[ \t]*/', '$1', $tags);
$tags = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z ]+/', '', $tags);
```

**Input**

```
tag       tag2 another-tag
```

**Output**

```
tag tag anothertag
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be simply:

To Remove Numeric and dash:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/[0-9\-]/", "", $tags);
```

Then to remove multiple spaces:

```
$tags = preg_replace("/[\s]{2,}/", " ", $tags);
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regexr.com?32g9g)**

Comment: This will replace non-letter, non-space characters with spaces instead of removing them.

Comment: Now it will remove the spaces instead of collapsing them into one ;)

Comment: Is it fine now..? @m.buettner

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be

```
[a-zA-Z ]+
```

This allows uppercase or lower case letter and a single space character combinations.

Comment: As @m.buettner said, it could contain consecutive spaces, but I also want the reverse of this, since I'm using preg_replace.